# Build system not automatically selected

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Present is the following build system for SASS files.

```
{
    "cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error", "--no-cache", "--style", "compressed"],

    "selector": "source.sass, source.scss", 
    "line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",

    "osx":
    {
        "path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    },

    "windows":
    {
        "shell": "true"
    },

    "working_dir": "$file_path",
}
```

This script works perfectly for `.scss` files and, when a `.scss` file is open, it is automatically selected and `Cmd+B` builds the source. But this is not the case for .sass files. There, `Build` is greyed out until the build system is selected manually. What can be done do fix this behaviour?

Comment: I'm guessing you have but did you verify that source.sass is the appropriate selector? Have you tried removing the source.scss just to verify if it's the combination of entries or the source.sass selector itself?

Comment: I already tried to switch the order and to have .sass the only selector - .scss, if specified, always works, but with a .sass file the system does never get selected.

Comment: I haven't done anything with SASS before, so this may seem odd but when you check the scope `cmd+alt+p` it is source.sass right?

Comment: This is really strange and I feel dumb for not noticing. For any reason the `.sass` file was associated as HAML and so the scope was `text.haml`. I just had to set `Open all files with the current extension as: SASS`. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can reward you with the bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you check the scope of the file is the same as your selector. `ctrl+shift+alt+p` in Windows and Linux and `cmd+alt+p` in OS X.